# Match from a key and return unique ID in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, network-analysis

The task: I webscraped a large data set that includes a variable (data$author) I need to clean. It's partly organized by job title, partly organized by name. I need this naming convention standardized for analysis by the correct job title held by the associated person's name. So, in my below example, Jim is the Prez, Bob is the CEO, etc. A further complication is that people move around in jobs over time, so the name-job link is associated by year. In short, I want to create a new variable in the dataframe with a standardized job title.

Here's my thinking: create a matching function to check each entry against the master key, and return the correct job title (by associated name+date) to a new vector.

```
jobs <- c("Prez", "CEO", "VP", "VP", "Director", "Assistant", "Secretary", "Intern")
names <- c("Susan", "Bob", "Susan", "Jim", "Gail", "Emily", "Dan", "Anne")
year <- c("86", "85-86", "85", "85-86", "85-86", "85-86", "85-86", "85-86")

key <- cbind(jobs, names, year)

DocID <- c(1:20)
author <- sample(c(jobs,names), 20, replace=T)
data <- cbind(DocID, author, year_data)

data$cleaned <- Magic.Clean.Function(data$author)
```

Hoping to end up with a 'data$cleaned' vector listing just the corrected job titles.

EDIT: Sorry if this is a little messy, I'm trying to recreate a simplified version of my actual DF. Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you show your expected

Comment: Your `data` do not have `year` column. Since titles varies over years, you need to include `year` in your data. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What are the values of `year_data`. Please edit your question with it.

Comment: I haven't built the key yet. So I can format the year_data in whatever makes sense. My original data is DDMMYY and lubridated so I imagine I'll continue with that format.

Answer (score 0):

```
library('data.table')
setDT(data)
setDT(key_df)
setnames(key_df, "names", "author")  # rename names to author column in key_df
data[key_df, on = c('author', 'year'), nomatch = 0]  # match on only author and year values between data and key_df datatables, and show the matched rows of data.
#    DocID author  year      jobs
# 1:    11  Susan    85        VP
# 2:     2    Jim 85-86        VP
# 3:    13   Gail 85-86  Director
# 4:     8  Emily 85-86 Assistant
# 5:    16  Emily 85-86 Assistant
# 6:     5   Anne 85-86    Intern
# 7:     6   Anne 85-86    Intern
```

OR

```
# if you want to add jobs column in your data
data[key_df, on = c('author', 'year'), jobs := jobs]
data
```

a vector of length(author) that returns the corrected job title

```
data[key_df, on = c('author', 'year'), nomatch = 0, author]
# [1] "Susan" "Jim"   "Gail"  "Emily" "Emily" "Anne"  "Anne" 

# unique authors
data[key_df, on = c('author', 'year'), nomatch = 0, unique(author)]
# [1] "Susan" "Jim"   "Gail"  "Emily" "Anne"
```

**Data:**

```
jobs <- c("Prez", "CEO", "VP", "VP", "Director", "Assistant", "Secretary", "Intern")
names <- c("Susan", "Bob", "Susan", "Jim", "Gail", "Emily", "Dan", "Anne")
year <- c("86", "85-86", "85", "85-86", "85-86", "85-86", "85-86", "85-86")

key_df <- data.frame(jobs, names, year, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DocID <- c(1:20)
set.seed(2L)
author <- sample(c(jobs,names), 20, replace=T)
data <- data.frame(DocID, author, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data$year <- c( key_df$year, key_df$year, key_df$year[1:4])
```

Comment: use the data posted in the answer. I changed names.

Comment: I think I see what you did (but I'll have to familiarize myself quickly with data.table).  But the result I need is a vector of length(author) that returns the corrected job title.

Comment: Still tinkering with it -- thanks for the help. I'll update when I know more!